# Get SSL error when trying to make a request from localhost to localhost in Next.js and Strapi

Tags: node.js, ssl, next.js, https, strapi

I make a GET request from http://localhost:3000, which is next.js (And it runs on node.js), to http://localhost:1337, which has strapi

I get the following error

write EPROTO 12500:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332

I couldn't find anything online. Has anyone encountered it? Please, help me, I'm frustrated and don't know what to do.

Comment: Is this relevant https://forum.strapi.io/t/ssl-protocol-error-on-localhost/1499/2?